# how to use UNION in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am unable to successfully join two independent tables using ".Union" in C# and show all the columns in a grid. Can someone tell me how I can resolve this?

```
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlCommand cmd1;
SqlCommand cmd2;

string cstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["college"]
                                  .ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cstr))
{
    cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from student where studentFirstName LIKE '%'+@studentFirstName+'%'", conn);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentFirstName", input1);
    cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from employee where empFirstName LIKE '%'+@empFirstName+'%'", conn);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empFirstName", input2);
    cmd = ((cmd1) .Union (cmd2));
}

SqlDataAdapter dAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
dAdapt.Fill(dSet);
```

Comment: I would suggest to better create a stored procedure then to write a complex query here!!

Comment: Why would you expect `Union` to work? It is a set operation that expect both sets to be type compatible (same number of columns, each column, in order, should be of the same type). As for it failing in C# - I would expect this to fail in SQL directly as well.

Comment: I'd recommend you go back to the basics and understand why you can't call a not existing method on some class. This looks like code was pushed around hoping it would work.

Answer (score 4):

There's no `union` method for `SqlCommand`. But you can call `Fill()` method several times on one dataset:

```
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter dAdapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
dAdapt1.Fill(dSet);
SqlDataAdapter dAdapt2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
dAdapt2.Fill(dSet);
```

May be you may consider to create stored procedure to do the union at server level.

2 things to note:

- calling `Fill()` multiple times is equivalent of `UNION ALL` (simple `UNION` eliminates duplicates);
- You can define PRIMARY KEY on table in your dataset and records from second fill will overwrite records from first fill with same primary key.

Comment: Note, that calling `Fill` multiple times would be be the equivalent of doing `UNION ALL` in SQL, not just `UNION`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yep, let me  change  the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Both the table should return same number of columns with same name in Union i think. Query like following might work:

```
SELECT StudentName As Name FROM Students WHERE StudentName LIKE 'abc%'
UNION
SELECT EmployeeName As Name FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeName LIKE 'abc%'
```

Comment: Have never seen C# syntax like that.. Question is how to do a UNION in C# code not a SQL query